# Post request with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, post, fetch

I'm currently trying to make a POST request in React for my app. In the previous version of my App, using AJAX I did a post request to this endpoint URL. Worked fine in the original and worked in Postman. (I could fill in the value for the key of :psid and do the post)

```
https://endpoint.com/viewquestion/:psid
```

However, when I transitioned to React and using the fetch method, it kept throwing up this error:

```
SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"
```

Could anyone please help me with this? Thank you!

Original Code (Jquery):

```
function ViewQuestion(psid) {
  $.ajax({
    url:
      "https://endpoint.com/viewquestion/" +
      psid,
    dataType: "text",
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
      console.log(data);
      // Logger(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
```

New Code (React):

```
viewQuestion: (ps_id) => {
  fetch(
    `https://endpoint.com/viewquestion/${ps_id}`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
    }
  )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: you're not sending any data, try adding `data: JSON.stringify({psid: ps_id})` to your fetch options

Comment: This isn't really a React problem, more of a fetch problem. But judging by the two functions, it looks like you haven't finished implementing the fetch call. You aren't sending any data, so your application is probably returning an error instead of json.

Comment: Thank you, I've added the lines but it's still giving the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be the response that you're getting from the server. In your original code you're not doing `response.json()` and now you are. Try removing that and console.log the response to see what you're getting and how to access that data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but it doesn't seem to work still for some reason... Same error as before

Comment: @ChunkyLow can we see the data you're sending back as a response? Try removing `res.json()` and instead try `console.log(res)` and remove the other `.then()` just to test. Add the results to your post, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Thank you, it works now! It seems that it was indeed a result of the res.json() which was messing it up

Comment: @ChunkyLow cool! I've updated the answer so you can mark it as a solution.